# How to log the output of deb install scripts?

Tags: apt, logs, deb

Running `apt-get install package` logs the terminal output to /var/log/apt/term.log and the summary info about installed packages to /var/log/apt/history.log. But I need to log what the package's preinst/postinst scripts are doing. Is it possible? Do I need to modify them myself to log anything?

Comment: The output from maintainer scripts ends up in `term.log` too. Do you want to log more than that? The actual commands run by all the maintainer scripts?

Comment: Yes, and the output of those commands